# If WP_ALLOW_REPAIR is not working, what can I do?

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

I'm being presented with the dreaded

> "Error establishing a database connection."

for mbgb.co.uk/blog - I've tried using:

`define('WP_ALLOW_REPAIR', true);` - normally this works fine, but I'm getting nothing this time. I've also tried testconnection.php, and I'm truly at a loss.

Can any advise?

Comment: is the db running?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone It certainly should be, how can I check this? I'm new to this but not that not that new unfortunately.

Comment: Try doing a table repair in MyPhpAdmin: https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/cpanel/cpanel-database-features/optimizing-and-repairing-mysql-databases-with-phpmyadmin